# SOAP web service unit/integration testing

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, jax-ws, integration-testing

My first version of the web service used plain `JDBC` to connect to the underlying database. I had written my Unit tests for the application using `JUnit`. I deployed this service on `Jboss EAP 6.4`. So far so good.

I altered my application code to use Jboss's JDBC connection pool. It seems like `Jboss 7+` does not allow referring to a data source externally (from outside the server). While the service still works fine , my unit tests are now broken. I am wondering how I can fix this.

I was thinking of re-writing same tests to test the service instead of the application code. One way to do this would be to generate the stubs using wsimport and then write a client. I can then use JUnit to test the client. The problem is one has to manually create the stubs and every time the WSDL changes

I am looking for an efficient way to accomplish this. What would be ideal is a framework that accepts a url for the `WSDL` (or url to the service) and then allow me to call the service operations.

I am aware that the above is no longer unit tests but integration tests. Is this approach the best way to test a `JAX-WS` service ?

Comment: SOAP UI, You can set up test cases for web service calls and also run WSI Compliance reports. A MUST have for any serious web-services development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JaxWsProxyFactoryBean](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.html) to get a client automatically, its not fully dynamic, but more flexible than building the client manually.

*Note*: I use an abstract class for most of the setup & tests (e.g. constant test data, so I have 3 of these tests with varying setups

- using a mocked db (nearly a "pure" test of the ws
- with an in-memory db (a little faster to execute)
- against a test-db similar to production

which may help you as well, since it sounds you want some fine(r)-grained tests in some cases.

**Spring (test) config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
   http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:endpoint id="myService"
                implementor="#serviceBean"
                address="http://localhost:9000/MyService"/>

<!-- id is used so we can access this via @Inject @Qualifier("serviceClientId") in the test class -->
<bean id="serviceClientId" class="package.MyService"
      factory-bean="proxyFactory"
      factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="proxyFactory"
      class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="package.MyService"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:9000/DeliveryService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="deliveryServiceBean" class="package.MyServiceImpl"/>
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-config.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,})
@Transactional
public class TestIntegrationMyService extends TestMyService {

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("serviceClientId")
    public void setClient(MyService client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Test
    public void validRequestShouldWork() throws Exception {
        client.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used SOAPUI API to write my integration tests.Created it as maven project. Its a pain to get hold of all the dependencies. But once you are past that step its smooth sailing. http://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html

Comment: so, that's a little more flexible in the terms that you do not need the (Java) Interface of the WS (if it even exists), but I guess building more complex request bodies is a little burdensome using this setup?